# Hide legend for zero values

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I found very challenging to show two graphs next to each other, so that the two chart areas shall be of equal length.

But as there's even a gap in some legends, I suppose I could just supply zeros or null as values in my (sorry, CSV) data, and then hide the corresponding legends. I tried legendFormatter, which could hide the text but didn't hide the colour square.

And by hiding, I mean leaving blank space in place of null values.

[Picture of desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFP3L.png)

Could you please help? I'm quite new to jQuery.

```
Firefox 40
IE  20
Chrome  15
Edge    10
Safari  5
null    0
Other   7
Text browsers   3
```

This fiddle is a start. I hided the legends with some correction fluid.

http://jsfiddle.net/3zqeqq38/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap `Legend.prototype.renderItem` method, and there decide whether legend item should or not, be visible. Snippet:

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.Legend.prototype, 'renderItem', function (p, item) {
    p.call(this, item);

    if(item.y === 0) {
      item.legendGroup.hide();
    } else {
      item.legendGroup.show();
    }
  });
})(Highcharts)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e48xa51L/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to strip those values from your `<pre>` tags.  Something like this should work:

```
$('#chart-sectors-csv').text($('#chart-sectors-csv').text().replace(/null(.*)0/g,""));

$('#chart-drivers-csv').text($('#chart-drivers-csv').text().replace(/null(.*)0/g,""));
```

That will remove the values, you might still want to do some formatting for chart size.

You can see it working here:  http://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/v0yyajsj/4/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your effort. But the idea was to hide the legends which are null or zero. As I mentioned it is quite difficult to align two graphs so the pies and yellow backgrounds are same size. And at the same time there needs to be a gap in the legend on the left.

Comment: @JosefHabr you're going to have to do some manipulation of the chart size to keep them the same height.  Have a look at http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setSize

Comment: I'm afraid that setSize again manipulates the whole chart including legends. Fitting the two to be the same size with different legend count might be very challenging. Using null values is a workaround which works, and there's that bonus of possibility of a gap in legends.